# Convert individual postgres jsonb array elements to row elements

Tags: postgresql, jsonb

I have to query a table with 2 columns, id and content. Id is just a uuid and the content column looks like

```
    {
  "fields": [
    {
      "001": "mig00004139229"
    },
    {
      "856": {
        "ind1": " ",
        "ind2": " ",
        "subfields": [
          {
            "u": "https://some.domain.com"
          },
          {
            "z": "some text"
          }
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "999": {
        "subfields": [
          {
            "i": "81be1acf-11df-4d13-a5c6-4838e3a808ee"
          },
          {
            "s": "3a6aa357-8fd6-4451-aedc-13453c1f2296"
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

I need to select the id, 001, and 856 elements where the subfield "u" domain matches a string "domain.com" so the output would be

| id | 001 | 856 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 81be1acf-11df-4d13-a5c6-4838e3a808ee | mig00004139229 | https://some.domain.com |

If this were a flat table, the query would correspond with "select id, 001, 856 from table where 856 like '%domain.com%'"

I can select individual columns based on the criteria I need, but they appear in separate rows except the id which appears with any other individual field in a regular select statement. How would I get the other fields to appear in the same row since it's part of the same record?

Unfortunately, my postgres version doesn't support jsonb_path_query, so I've been trying something along the lines of:

```
SELECT id, jsonb_array_elements(content -> 'fields') -> '001', 
     jsonb_array_elements(content -> 'fields') -> '856' -> 'subfields'
FROM 
     mytable
WHERE....
```

This method returns the data I need, but the individual elements arrive on separate rows with the with the id in the first column and nulls for every element that is neither the 001 nor 856 e.g.

| id | 001 | 856 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| id_for_first_record | 001_first_record | null |
| id_for_first_record | null | null |
| id_for_first_record | null | null |
| id_for_first_record | null | 856_first_record |
| id_for_second_record | 001_second_record | null |
| id_for_second_record | null | null |
| id_for_second_record | null | null |
| id_for_second_record | null | 856_second_record |

Usable, but clunky so I'm looking for something better

Comment: can you add the SQL you're trying to use and what it returns now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think my query can help you. There are different ways to resolve this, I am not sure if this is the best approach.

I use `jsonb_path_query()` function with the path for the specified `JSON` value.

```
SELECT 
       id,  
       jsonb_path_query(content, '$.fields[*]."001"') AS "001",
       jsonb_path_query(content, '$.fields[*]."856".subfields[*].u') AS "856"
FROM t
WHERE jsonb_path_query_first(content, '$.fields[*]."856".subfields[*].u' )::text ilike '%domain%';
```

Output:

| id | 001 | 856 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 81be1acf-11df-4d13-a5c6-4838e3a808ee | "mig00004139229" | "https://some.domain.com" |

**UPDATED:** because of Postgresql version is prior to 12.

You could try something like this, but I think there must be a better approach:

```
SELECT 
       t.id,
       max(sq1."001") AS "001",
       max(sq2."856") AS "856"
       
FROM t
INNER JOIN (SELECT id, (jsonb_array_elements(content -> 'fields') -> '001')::text AS "001" FROM t) AS sq1 ON t.id = sq1.id
INNER JOIN (SELECT id, (jsonb_array_elements(jsonb_array_elements(content -> 'fields') -> '856' -> 'subfields') -> 'u')::text AS "856" FROM t) AS sq2 ON t.id = sq2.id

WHERE sq2."856" ilike '%domain%'

GROUP BY t.id;
```

Comment: Unfortunately, the version I have doesn't support jsonb_path_query, @melcher I just started the query beginning with SELECT 
       id,  
       jsonb_array_elements(content -> 'fields') -> '001',
    jsonb_array_elements(content -> 'fields') -> '856' -> 'subfields' The problem I'm getting is each data element I want is being returned on a separate row (e.g. id appears with 001 but null in 856 column, id appears with 856 but with null in 001 column). I can work with this, but I'd prefer to do it in the DB

Comment: Ok, I updated my answer. You can most likely find a better approach, although my query can give you an idea how to deal with the problem.

Comment: @KyleBanerjee You should edit your question with the query you try and tag your Postgresql version.